# How to install libssl-dev ,libffi-dev on Mac os?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I can install `libssl-dev` and `libffi-dev` on Ubuntu with the command `apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev`, But I can't install on Mac; I have tried using the command: `brew install libssl-dev libffi` but not working for me.

What do I need to do to get homebrew to install this?

Comment: `brew install libffi` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707470/32453

Answer (score 36):

Those particular packages do not exist under those names on both MacPorts and Homebrew - hence the errors you are receiving. In order to install these particular packages on OS X, you will want to use `openssl`. The following command should help you out:

```
brew install openssl
```

If you already have `openssl` installed, try running the following in order to repair it - [some users over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767569/django-cant-find-libssl-on-os-x-mavericks) reported this as a fix when trying to get Django working.

```
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Comment: How do you do it without brew and without sudo?

Comment: `openssl` is not the same as `libssl-dev`. The first one is for direct use, the second is for linking. UPD: ok, for mac they are bundled in one package, but you need to run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, you can download openssl and compile it from source on the mac and install it to a custom path or folder. I needed it for the "links" browser.

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to get [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/) off the ground on MacOS Mojave and ran into a similar issue.

This is the error message I was seeing:

```
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc "${@}" -o '/Users/mymbp/.cache/crystal/crystal-run-server.tmp'  -rdynamic  
`command -v pkg-config > /dev/null && pkg-config --libs --silence-errors libssl || printf %s '-lssl -lcrypto'` `command -v pkg-config > /dev/null && pkg-config --libs
 --silence-errors libcrypto || printf %s '-lcrypto'` -lz -lpcre -lgc -lpthread 
/usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.27.0/src/ext/libcrystal.a -levent -liconv -ldl -
L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib`
```

Searching */usr/local/lib* I noticed there was no mention of libssl.

So I added a symlink and that seemed to fix it.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Note: The current version of openssl that brew drops is 1.0.2p, your version may be different.

Comment: Similar issue, with crystal as well. I was able to `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` and get it running per here: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795#issuecomment-337006164

Answer (score 5):

`openssl` was already installed, but I could not build `psycopg2` because it was complaining about missing `-lssl`. I've followed the steps from [Simon Sheehan](https://superuser.com/a/1091221/146465) but it was still not available.

But looking at the message after force linking openssl:

```
For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

So I did what it says. I've added those two lines in my `~/.bashrc`. And `psycopg2` builded without errors this time.

Comment: On MacOS  `/usr/local/opt/openssl` already points to `../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i`, could it be a case that `pip install psycopg2` doesn't follow symlinks? Doesn't seem reasonable!

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I already have
`env | grep FLAGS ==> LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libpq/lib    CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libpq/include`

Comment: Here's the solution (I was getting an error about libssl) https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159643/1459079

Answer (score 0):

For Macports, install `sudo port install openssl` and set your environment variables as below.

```bsh
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include/openssl"
```

I found out about these locations via the command `port contents openssl | grep -v "man"`